# How to add existing bot on a website with minimize capability

Tags: botframework, bots, web-chat

BotFramework v3 Nodejs SDK 
Channels added: MS teams , Cortana and WebChat

We would like access or integrate existing production bot from a website hosted in corporate network. After doing some research I found 
[BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/v3) has some ways of integration that ranges from Easiest to Hard. I am looking for specific example where I would like ability to place Bots chat window on the right down corner of webpage and, user should have a ability to minimize the bot window when not needed.

The ways mentioned on the repo page simply drops web chat box on the page but, doesn't have ability to minimize it.

The ways mentioned on the repo page simply drops web chat box on the page but, doesn't have ability to minimize it.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/12.customization-minimizable-web-chat

Comment: @vijayI hope you got it working! If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" it so I can clear this ticket from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the Web Chat v3 branch which is currently deprecated, and even though you wrote your bot in the v3 SDK, you can still use Web Chat v4. If you look at the samples in the Web Chat master branch - v4 - there is a [Minimizable Web Chat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/12.customization-minimizable-web-chat) example.

Another approach is to connect your bot to Facebook Messenger and use the [Customer Chat Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/). Note, the Messenger Plugin is not nearly as customizable as Web Chat but is a quick and simple way to add a minimizable bot your webpage.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I looked at your suggestion but, I have no experience with React so difficult to understand fully. Also I am wondering if website where I want to embed is not react then how to implement minimize way.

Comment: Did you found out how to do it without react? @vijay